# req.user is undefined when accessing other routes after passport authentication

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis, passport.js

I'm using the custom error handling of passportjs. When I finished authenticating and now redirect to other route, the req.user is now undefined on that route. Are there any configurations I need to do?

```
(req: any, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local-register', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next('Error Auth');
      }
      if (info) {
        return next('Error Auth');
      }
      if (!user) {
        return next('Error Auth'); 
      }
      req.logIn(user, (error: Error) => {
        if (error) {
          return next('Error Auth');
        }
        return next();
      });

    })(req, res, next);
```

```
app.get('/home', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user.id) // logs undefined
})
```

session.js file includes

```
const sessions = session({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : 'auto',
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
  },
  name: 'sessionID',
  genid: () => {
    return nanoid(36);  
  },
  resave: false, 
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET ?? '',  
  saveUninitialized: false, 
  store: new Reddistore({ client: redisClient }),
});
```

my index.js file includes

```
  app.use(sessions);
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your index.js file

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { passportStrategy } = require('./config/passportStrategy');
passportStrategy(passport);
```

in config/passportStrategy.js file

```
const {
  Strategy, ExtractJwt 
} = require('passport-jwt');
const User = require('../model/user');

const passportStrategy = (passport) => {
  const options = {};
  options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  options.secretOrKey = "YOUR_SECRET";
  passport.use('local-register',
    new Strategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
      try {
        const result = await User.findOne({ _id: payload.id });
        if (result) {
          return done(null, result.toJSON());
        }
        return done('No User Found', {});
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error,{});
      }
    })
  );   
};

module.exports = { passportStrategy };
```

// your middleware should like this

```
(req: any, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local-register', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next('Error Auth');
      }
      if (info) {
        return next('Error Auth');
      }
      if (!user) {
        return next('Error Auth'); 
      }
      req.user = user; // <=== assign user to req.user
      req.logIn(user, (error: Error) => {
        if (error) {
          return next('Error Auth');
        }
        return next();
      });

    })(req, res, next);


app.get('/home', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user.id) // now you can access user
})
```

Comment: For people that encounter this problem, I've researched that you need to manually serialize or save the registered data manually to sessions if youre using custom passport callback. (err, user, info) the "user" parameter is equal to the login info then manually save it to req.user. Dont forget to do req.session.save inside the req.logIn because if you don't, the data you saved will be lost. Basically the passport.serialize and passport.deserialize are useless and you can delete it because youre serializing the data manually.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, I just explained how things worked.